# SQL last gift was 10 years ago

Tags: sql

I'm sorry if this is all wrong, teaching myself SQL at work

We have two data sets: `EntityDet` (a.) and `GiftDet` (b.)

EntityDet has all the bio information of people and GiftDet has all the gift info of those people.

I want to aggregate anyone the people from entitydet that had a last gift 10 years ago from today 2017.10.10

Date_of_record is the place in giftDet that has the gift date stamp on for records. They both have ID_numbers that connect them.

Here is what I was thinking but it is not working

```
select ID_NUMBER
from ENTITYDET_NYU_T a. 
select *from GIFTDET b.
max date_of_record b. 
where date of record <=2008.10.16 b.
select date_of_record 
slext max (date of record))
where a.id_number = b.id_number
```

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM EntityDet 
WHERE 
    id_number IN ( SELECT a.id_number
                   FROM EntityDet a
                       INNER JOIN GiftDet b ON a.id_number = b.id_number
                   GROUP BY a.id_number
                   HAVING MAX([date of record]) < '20071010' )
```

Comment: thanks Sarslan...if I want to add the below columns from the Entitydet table do I just add a. then the column name....example   SELECT a.id_number, a.Record_status_Desc, a.Pref_name 
FROM 
    EntityDet a
    INNER JOIN GiftDet b ON a.id_number = b.id_number
GROUP BY a.id_number
HAVING MAX([date of record]) < '20071010'

Comment: how many columns you have? if one or two you can add this columns GROUP BY and SELECT part of the query. If it is too many then I recommend convert this query to subquery and join again with the EntityDet table.

Comment: HI! I have 17 columns from the EntityDet Table I want to out put...what do you mean so I start the code with "Group by select a.id_number, a.pref_name....etc"?

Comment: You are amazing one last question....if I was looking for pref_name in  ('John','jack', joe') do add that in the end?

Comment: If this column in EntityDet, you can.

Comment: the weird part Sarslan....when I plug in the query it is giving me everyone in GiftDet not just the people who's last gift was 10 years ago....what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What is your last query?